# Make tree command print & instead of &amp; (And other special characters) on JSON file

Tags: linux, bash

I've this example Tree structure

```
TreeTest/
├── something?.txt
└── something&.txt
```

I want to generate a JSON file of it to use it on another script, and i require the exact same names, since they are used as keys. I readed the man, and used this command `tree -J -o tree.json TreeTest/`, but it prints this

```
[
  {"type":"directory","name":"TreeTest/","contents":[
    {"type":"file","name":"something?.txt"},
    {"type":"file","name":"something&amp;.txt"}
  ]},
  {"type":"report","directories":0,"files":2}
]
```

With `&amp;` instead of just `&`. I tried using `tree -J -N -o tree.json TreeTest/` and `tree -J --charset utf8 -o tree.json TreeTest/`, but was the same output. How can i make the output be the exact names, using & and any other special character that could have this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest filing that as a bug against `tree` upstream. A correct JSON string containing `&` is just `"&"`; using HTML entities is simply wrong. That said, a bug in a 3rd-party tool is a matter for that tool's bug tracker, not for Stack Overflow.

Comment: (To be clear, `tree` is not part of bash, or part of Linux itself; it's its own tool -- the version NixOS uses comes from http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/, though your own Linux distro might use a different version).

Comment: But is this a bug, or just the lack of an option?

Comment: I see [it uses](https://github.com/execjosh/tree/blob/master/json.c#L119) it's own [html_encode](https://github.com/execjosh/tree/blob/master/html.c#L403) function. The encoding function is wrong for json. For example line feed should be converted to `\f` but is not.

Comment: @Efraín, it claims to be JSON output. The content is *not* correct JSON encoding of the literal data, but is instead a JSON encoding of an HTML representation of the literal data. I don't see anything other than "bug" here, but feel free to email the author -- whose contact info is on the page I linked, if it's that version of `tree` your distro ships -- and point them to this question so they can weigh in themselves. :)

Comment: Ok, then i'll fill a bug report, anyway i'll leave the question open in case someone has another solution, thanks.

Comment: I've written [this patch](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/tree2/-/commit/f1e85cd8931f9fdcdad5d47f923dc3c0504d1387) and mailed the author.

Comment: That seems like it would fail for non-English input like `"piña colada"` or `"你好"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until this can be fixed and deployed everywhere:

```sh
tree . -J | recode html..utf8
```

But this fail with "piña colada" or "你好"

The perl alternative works with all:

```sh
tree . -J | perl -n -mHTML::Entities -e 'print HTML::Entities::decode_entities($_)'
```

Sample output:

```
[
  {"type":"directory","name":".","contents":[
    {"type":"file","name":"a"},
    {"type":"file","name":"a&"},
    {"type":"file","name":"<a>&c"},
    {"type":"file","name":"b"},
    {"type":"file","name":"c"},
    {"type":"file","name":"d"},
    {"type":"file","name":"e"},
    {"type":"file","name":"f"},
    {"type":"file","name":"filename.R10011.out"},
    {"type":"file","name":"g"},
    {"type":"file","name":"h"},
    {"type":"file","name":"i"},
    {"type":"file","name":"j"},
    {"type":"file","name":"k"},
    {"type":"file","name":"l"},
    {"type":"file","name":"piña colada"},
    {"type":"directory","name":"r","contents":[
    ]},
    {"type":"file","name":"你好"}
  ]},
  {"type":"report","directories":1,"files":17}
]
```